# Soap request using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, api, soap, curl, wsdl

I'm trying to send a SOAP post via Curl in PHP but I always get a couldn't connect to host problem.
But when i trie to use the same URL in a web based client like hurl, a got the correct response :

- Hurl Test :[http://www.hurl.it](http://www.hurl.it/hurls/2a4fa2c965399c8768285304d0a7f2f0db99c6d8/bd6b209899f51a4117bbb77ca931d120f780d1b4)
- My code :

  ```
      $url = "https://gateway.monster.com/bgwBroker";

      $soapMessage = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' .
          '<SOAP-ENV:Header>'.
          '<mh:MonsterHeader xmlns:mh="http://schemas.monster.com/MonsterHeader">'.
            '<mh:MessageData>'.
              '<mh:MessageId>PresenceMedia SARL Jobs</mh:MessageId>'.
              '<mh:Timestamp>2004-06-09T14:41:44Z</mh:Timestamp>'.
            '</mh:MessageData>'.
          '</mh:MonsterHeader>'.
          '<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext">'.
            '<wsse:UsernameToken>'.
              '<wsse:Username>xrtpjobsx01</wsse:Username>'.
              '<wsse:Password>rtp987654</wsse:Password>'.
            '</wsse:UsernameToken>'.
          '</wsse:Security>'.
        '</SOAP-ENV:Header>'.
        '<SOAP-ENV:Body>'.
          '<Job jobRefCode="Job - minimal fields" jobAction="addOrUpdate" jobComplete="true" xmlns="http://schemas.monster.com/Monster" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.monster.com/Monster http://schemas.monster.com/Current/xsd/Monster.xsd">'.
            '<RecruiterReference>'.
              '<UserName>xrtpjobsx01</UserName>'.
            '</RecruiterReference>'.
            '<JobInformation>'.
              '<JobTitle><![CDATA[PresenceMedia SARL its a simple test from morocco blablablablablablablablablablablabla]]></JobTitle>'.
              '<JobStatus monsterId="4">JobTypeFullTime</JobStatus>'.
              '<PhysicalAddress>'.
                '<City>Rabat Shore</City>'.
                '<State>NY</State>'.
                '<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>'.
                '<PostalCode>11220</PostalCode>'.
              '</PhysicalAddress>'.
              '<JobBody><![CDATA[PresenceMedia SARL Body blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla blablabla]]></JobBody>'.
            '</JobInformation>'.
            '<JobPostings>'.
              '<JobPosting>'.
                '<Location>'.
                  '<City>London East</City>'.
                  '<State>London</State>'.
                  '<CountryCode>UK</CountryCode>'.
                '</Location>'.
                '<JobCategory monsterId="47" />'.
                '<JobOccupations>'.
                  '<JobOccupation monsterId="11909" />'.
                '</JobOccupations>'.
                '<BoardName monsterId="1" />'.
                '<Industries>'.
                  '<Industry>'.
                    '<IndustryName monsterId="1" />'.
                  '</Industry>'.
                '</Industries>'.
              '</JobPosting>'.
            '</JobPostings>'.
          '</Job>'.
        '</SOAP-ENV:Body>'.
      '</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

      $headers = array(             
              "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"", 
              "Accept: text/xml", 
              "Cache-Control: no-cache", 
              "Pragma: no-cache", 
              "SOAPAction: \"run\"", 
              "Content-length: ".strlen($soapMessage),
          ); 

      $soapUser = "xrtpjobsx01";
      $soapPassword = "rtp987654";

      $soap_do = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_PORT, 8443);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser.":".$soapPassword);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);   
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );        
      curl_setopt($soap_do,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,9000);    
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soapMessage); 
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);


      $result = curl_exec($soap_do);
      $err = curl_error($soap_do);

      echo "Result:" . $result;
      echo "<br>Error:" . $err ;

      echo "<b><pre>";
      var_dump(curl_getinfo($soap_do));
      echo "</pre>";


      ?>
  ```

Comment: What is $result printing?

Comment: Hi fabio, 
the result printing is : Couldn't connect to host !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php use simple Soapclient to post reponse. and check he response also check if the port used for connection is free.

```
$client = new SoapClient($Url, $options);
$data = $client->functionName($params);
```

Comment: I Already use SoapClient, but still generating errors.
When i trie to acces to my Uri with a web browser i got the error "This webpage is not available", the same thing when i trie to post data with Curl or SoapClient, wut when i use the web based client "Ex: Hurt" Everything was perfect !!

Comment: Well it is not always easy to send required soap message through php SoapClient. As php generate soap message by its own way. You may need (Soap Client's doRequest method)[http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php] for accomplish this.